# function call giving error of incompatible type of argument

Tags: c, function, structure, function-call

I have gone under a problem while coding in c (i am not experienced programmer).
I have a structure like this

```
struct afreq
{
    int freq;
    unsigned char sym;      
    short int left,right,next;      
};
```

in main function :

```
struct afreq data[50] ;
```

int size = manipulation(data, count);    //this function do some manipulation and
 returns size of int type.And i use this size in the function call below:

```
dictionary(data,var,size);
```

The problem creating part is here:

```
///////////////////////////// Definition of Dictionary function /////////////////////////////////////////


  dictionary(struct afreq data[] ,char *var,size_t dataSize)// function definition create problem in first argument when caled from the another recursive function call inside this function.
dictionary(struct afreq data[] ,char *var,size_t dataSize)
    { 
    int i;
    printf("\n data: %d\n", dataSize);
    for(i=2;i<dataSize;++i)
    {
    if(data[i].left=='\0')
    { int correspondance[data[30];
       char temp[30];
       strcpy(temp, var);
        strcat(temp, "0");
        printf("check1");   
     dictionary(data[correspondance[data[i].left]], temp,dataSize); //error here
    }  
    printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

What i want to do using this? 
I have to read the alphabets from a file given as sole argument. The file is "Input.txt" and contains inside 'abcdef' (i calculate their frequency in my program) and then i save them in an array in the format [symbol  Frequency LeftChild RightChild] (example: [a 1 0 0] [b 2 0 0 ] [c 3 a b]  etc.(it's like huffman code)).
Up to here i have done everything properly. But when i try to print the dictionary like (as we have in huffman (path in o and 1)) (In the example we can see that "c" is parent and path of "a" is "o" and "b" is "1"). To implement this part i have written the code above, which creates error in first argument of function call.
Here is the complete code (But please do not forget to include "Input.txt" file at sole argument which contains "abcdef" .

```
Here is the output:



 hp@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Internship_Xav/Task2$ gcc ttask.c -o ttask
improve.c: In function ‘dictionary’:
improve.c:85:2: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘dictionary’
improve.c:74:1: note: expected ‘struct afreq *’ but argument is of type ‘struct afreq’
```

Comment: `data[i].left` type is `short int`

Comment: so many problems there.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY do you have any solution for my problem (i am obliged not to use pointers, other wise i would have done it yet.) could you please help me? thanks. (the one tried to anser below has exactly understood what i ant to do. but how to achieve it by creating tables? (not pointers) any snippet or guidance please ?)

Comment: @Dipto thanks for the help. actually the "Blaise" have exactly unf=derstood my question. You can read that to precisely understand that what i want to achieve. But i don't know how to achieve by creating tables(becausei don't have to use pointers)

Comment: I think that you should think long and hard about what you should pass to the function.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, Ok. But do you have any idea how to do that? I have attached full code here if you could help me ?

Comment: You will probably be on your own.

Comment: I doubt you need a linked list, and for that, your structure is wrong. By `left` and `right` you wanted to move to other nodes, so you need to store their addresses there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is, essentially, what your compiler says it is. You are passing, as first argument, `data[i].left`, which is of type short int, whereas a pointer to `struct afreq` is needed. The only reason why it compiles anyway is because gcc, by default, allows conversions between int and pointer (but there's not many reasons why you would want to do that).

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do - you want to call recursively your "dictionary" function on what seems to be a tree. The problem is that that structure is not really well defined. You are trying to "index" the nodes of the tree with their value (that's what I understand with the `data[i].left`), but there is no way to "make the link" between, say, `'a'`, and "the `struct afreq` that has `'a'` as a symbol. You either need to make a correspondance table somewhere and make a call to it, or you need to transform `left` and `right` in your structure into pointers to the corresponding structure.

Good luck!

Comment: yes you have understood me.  but i am obliged not to use pointers. Could you please still explain me how to achieve now ? any piece of code for help please ?

Comment: I am not able to understand by "make a table" and call it ? could you please xplain me this , any piece of code ? (if possible, thanks)

Comment: One way to do this would be to define a correspondance table, say
`int correspondance[26]`. For every symbol `sym` that you encounter, you store in correspondance[sym - 'a'] the index of the corresponding `afreq` element, and then you call to `dictionary(data[correspondance[data[i].left]]). It's not ideal, but it should work. You can also manage you data array so that it takes [sym-`a`] as an index but I don't know if it's an option for your use case.
I'm afraid I can't provide much code because, quite frankly, the current state of the code is too messy for me to be motivated to dig in...

Comment: When i do what you asked me to do then i get error: improve.c:85:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘dictionary’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default] improve.c:74:1: note: expected ‘struct afreq *’ but argument is of type ‘short int’ , Any solution for it ? Thanks (But 1 thing i am not able to understand, how it changed it's data type when we inserted correspondance[data[i].left] inside data[])? I mean beofre the error was "short int" but now the error is "argument is of type ‘struct afreq"

Comment: Ah, yes, good point, sorry about that, I was too fast. What you may want to do is add a parameter to your dictionary function - for instance `index`, or whatever. The way you'd use that is you'd pass, as first argument, `data`, always; and as `index` the index of the place you are looking at (so in your recursive call case, `correspondance[data[i].left]]`. And then in the code of the function you call to data[index], and this should yield the things that you want. Maybe. Possibly. (I'm saying this because I didn't test it, so...)

Comment: As for you second question, the data type changed because... well, it changed: data[something] is of type struct afreq because data is an array of these. If this is not clear to you, maybe you should look at your code and try to think, for every variable occurrence and composition thereof, what type that thing is. It may also help you understand what to do/how to do it. Good luck.